# Is it a bad design to create a small class with two methods solely for inheritance?

Tags: oop, inheritance

I want to create a class with two methods, and no other purpose than so I can create two subclasses which inherit the methods. This class cannot function on its own. Is this a bad programming design or habit?

Comment: Always important to question those who say "this belongs on" as they are often wrong.  Also, abstract classes.  Look into them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are even classes that don't do anything, other than letting other classes derive from it. It doesn't matter whether the superclass can have useful instances themselves. Classes that only exist for other classes to derive from are often called abstract classes; some languages such as C++ also have syntax features to allow the compiler to give errors when you try to create an object from an abstract class. So it can't be THAT bad to have classes like this.

Beyond that, what's "bad practice"? If the setup makes the code easier to understand then it can't be bad.

Of course, if the two classes you intend to derive really don't have anything in common and those two methods are merely "hey, I noticed that 10 lines of code in that class are the same as these 10 lines in the other class", then making this into a common superclass may confuse more than help. Classes should still have some form of relationship. If it's just about sharing some code that randomly happens to show up here and there, standalone functions might be a better choice.

Basically, look at the names of the classes. If your new superclass is named something along the lines of "Some very generic name 'cause I have no idea what it is", then it's probably not "good design". If, on the other hand, you have a proper name for the superclass, and the names of the derived classes are still something that has a "kind of" relationship to the superclass, then it's probably not a bad thing.

Another strong hint for something being "good" is when you start using pointers to the superclass because you don't care whether you're dealing with one or the other subclass.

Comment: Good post! I will vote this answer afterward. I can't decide if they relates, but they depend on each other. I have also though of merging these two class into one. I have one class that display a series of text that loads from a property list. Then another class display a certain sprite/picture that also loads from a property list that correspond to the text that is being display. Both class have two methods: loadValueFromPlist and displayNextValue. Inside loadValueFromPlist is didPlistLoad which do some things after it finish. I want to create a supercalss that contain these method.

Comment: I'm sorry for the double post, but I reached the max text limit. I wanted to name the superclass, "PropertyLoader" which contain the three methods listed before. The two classes inherited this and will override didPlistLoad to do some specific actions. All other methods remain intact. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: to clarify Christian Stiebers post: dont use inheritance to save lines of code. thats bad design. the classes should have an "kind of" relationship. your "PropertyLoader" "TextLoader"/"ImageLoader" example seems to be ok (imho).

Comment: I decide to not create this class, but rather change the similar method so it function differently. I will vote this answer as it answered my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good habit, it leads to better organization of functions. Another reason is you can just look at the inheritance tree and know that it is related to the two function class. There isn't much harm in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no inherent good or bad, in general. It depends a lot on the specifics of situation. But, in general, you should always try to follow the principles of object-orientation. For example, whenever you are creating a class, whether abstract or concrete, the class should have both **data** and **behaviour**. This rule is very important, it goes all the way to the very foundation of object-orientation. A class without data, is just a bunch of methods (this is procedural programming, not OO). A class without behavior, is a bunch of variables (again procedural, not OO). So, having both data and behavior together is important. But, they should have logical relation to each other, not randomly put together. For example, a method should access data in some way.

Of course, there are deviations from this rule. For example, you may have just a bunch of methods in a static class (like Math class in Java), or just a bunch of constanst in a Interface. But, they are exceptions not rule. They are there, out of necessity, for convenience. They are not true classes in the strict object-oriented sense.

So, always aim toward the right principles, and deviate only when there is no other way to accomplish it, and only as an exception, not as a rule.

1. The previous point was refering to how to structure a class. For designing relationship among classes, again, the logical path should be followed. Think through each concept that you are dealing with and see if each one makes sense as a class, and then see what is the relationship among these classes. If it looks the you have three concepts that can be organized in inheritance - two classes deriving from a parent, the so be it. If the parent class has two methods, its ok. Even if it has one method, it is still OK. As long as it represents a coherent logical unit.